# Spring-Cloud-Kubernetes propertySource order

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-kubernetes

I am trying to understand, where Spring-Cloud-Kubernetes propertySource will fit in the propertySource order. Will they have higher precedance that all other propertySources?

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-kubernetes/1.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#kubernetes-propertysource-implementations

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config